# In the movie "Identity", did the murders really happen?

Tags: plot-explanation, identity

I realize this entire question is one big spoiler, so there's no way around it.

I'm confused by the ending of *[Identity](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0309698/)*.  Did those murders actually happen?  Was John Cusack at the motel, or was it a dream?